# Extension Five Server Ver 0.1.9 of Microsoft Studio Code Ver 17.2.1

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a problem with configuring the FIVE SERVER Ver 0.1.9 extension in Microsoft Visual Studio Code Ver 1.72.1.
I want to set the browser on CHROME incognito (private mode)
I tried adding the following line

```
"fiveServer.browser": ["chrome –incognito"]
```

When I start the local FIVE SERVER server on the http://127.0.0.1:5555/ port it is not taken as a broswer set in the file setting.json that is CHROME and in the incognito version (private mode).
I would like the FIVE SERVER extension to open the web page in the CHROME IN INCOGNITO browser.
How can I solve this?

Link extension : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yandeu.five-server

Comment: "it does not work" is not a precise enough error description. What **exactly* does not work? What do you expect to happen, what happens instead? Show all errors and error messages you get. Please edit your question and add those details.

Comment: I'm also hoping for an answer.  I think the question is obvious.  He wants the server to start up in chrome in incognito mode.  What is hard about understanding that.  Hope an answer can be provided soon.